# Regex for whitelisting specific IP segments

Tags: regex, iis, ip, url-rewriting, whitelist

I need a regex that I haven't been able to figure out:

How do I take something like this:

```
60.70.80.90/25
```

And turn it into a regex that will match IPs in that range?

That IP address is just a dummy; the actual IP range is different.  Is there a way to turn that into a regex, without enumerating every single address in that range?  For example, I know I could do this:

```
60\.70\.80\.91|...
```

But I'd rather not have to enumerate all those addresses.  Anyone able to figure out a regex for this?

This will be used in an IIS rewrite rule to whitelist specific IP's, and deny access to all others.

EDIT:
If you have a better idea for whitelisting IP's other than what I've suggested, feel free to suggest accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't use a regex for this... is there some reason you feel a regex is necessary?

Comment: Feel free to suggest a different approach!

Comment: You should edit your question to ask for any approach, then.

Comment: Question updated accordingly; thanks.

Comment: Note that 60.70.80.90/25 is not a valid netmask; did you mean 60.70.80.0/25?

Comment: This is just a dummy address, as indicated in the question.  The actual value is different, but has the format x.y.z.w/m

Comment: There's not an easy, general way to turn a CIDR into a regex. If you needed a specific CIDR turned into a regex, I could probably do it. If you need a general solution, please provide the code you're working on, and we can help you debug it.

Comment: Reminded me of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/writing-firewall-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny  from all
  Allow from 60.70.80.90/25
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex is entirely the wrong tool for this task.  Regexes are good for text manipulation; netmask math is a math operation.  It is *possible* to do this with a regex, but it's very ugly, very confusing, and very inefficient!

Your best bet is to use a library for IP and network manipulations, such as [Net::CIDR](http://search.cpan.org/~mrsam/Net-CIDR-0.17/CIDR.pm) for Perl.  If you can't use one for some reason, do the manipulations yourself:

1. Convert the dotted-decimal format into its numeric equivalent:

   ```
   60.70.80.90/25 -> 1011241050/4294967168
   ```
2. Convert the IP to be matched into its numeric form:

   ```
   1.2.3.4 -> 16909030
   ```
3. AND the target IP against the netmask:

   ```
   16909030 & 4294967168 = 16908928
   ```
4. AND the whitelisted IP against he netmask:

   ```
   1011241050 & 4294967168 = 1011240960
   ```
5. If the results match, it's a match:

   16908928 == 1011240960 ?  Then whitelist match

Comment: I agree the math would be pretty straightforward in code, but I need to slot this in via an IIS rewrite rule so that we don't have to redeploy an application every time we want to change the IP whitelist.  If you think that could be done in an IIS rewrite rule, that'd be great...

Comment: @KenMason: Sounds like a question for [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com/).